# Rails - Best way of retrieving future associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following situation.

I have a project model which have many meetings, which have a date.

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Model
    has_many :meetings
end

class Meeting < ActiveRecord::Model
    belongs_to :project

    validates_presence_of :meeting_date
end
```

What is the cleanes and most effiecient way to retrieve **future** meeting (i.e. meeting.meeting_date > Time.now)?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this in your meeting model:

```
scope :future_meetings, lambda{where(["meetings.meeting_date > ?",Time.now])}
```

Refer to it:

```
@project.meetings.future_meetings
```

Comment: It seems like :future should be a scope on Meeting, rather than a scope of project. Is there a way to cleanly define that scope and then get the future_meetings based on that?

Comment: I updated the answer. It should work, as the scope only defines a filter on the related meetings.

Comment: slightly more idiomatic to name the scope `future`, no need to repeat the model name.